# Dynamic count based on value

Tags: php

So, I have a two-dimensional array:

```
$fruits = array
  (
  array('fruit' => 'Apple', 'rating' => '2'),
  array('fruit' => 'Pear', 'rating' => '3'),
  array('fruit' => 'Peach', 'rating' => '2'),
  array('fruit' => 'Strawberry', 'rating' => '2')
  );
```

I need to get an explicit order. Therefore, taking the example above, I want to display a `table` containing three `col`s -> fruit, rating and rank. If there is any equality in the ratings then I want to have `radio buttons` in the third col with the possible ranks. This is what I mean:

[image]

So far I have the below piece of code which is only capable to tell whether there is another fruit with the same rating, and if yes it shows radios from 1-4. This is a very rude solution. So how can I easily build it up taking the fact into consideration that the rating can be anything. For e.g. 2-2-3-3 in which case I need radios 1-2,1-2 and 3-4,3-4.

PHP:

```
echo "<table><tr><td>fruit</td><td>rating</td><td>rank</td></tr>";
for($i = 0; $i < count($fruits); ++$i) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$fruits[$i]['fruit']."</td><td>".$fruits[$i]['rating']."</td><td>";    
    for($j = 0; $j < count($fruits); ++$j) {
        if($i != $j) {  
            if($fruits[$i]['rating'] == $fruits[$j]['rating']) {
                echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"".$fruits[$i]['fruit']."\" value=\"1\">1
                <input type=\"radio\" name=\"".$fruits[$i]['fruit']."\" value=\"2\">2
                <input type=\"radio\" name=\"".$fruits[$i]['fruit']."\" value=\"3\">3
                <input type=\"radio\" name=\"".$fruits[$i]['fruit']."\" value=\"4\">4"
                break;
            }
            else if ($j == 3)
            {
                echo "<b>".($i+1)."</b></td></tr>";
            }
        }
        else if ($j==3)
        {
            echo "<b>".($i+1)."</b></td></tr>";
        }
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Basically I need to have a count per rating for all the cases there is an equality.

**P.S.:** The array is already `DESC` sorted based on the ratings, this is why `($i+1)` works in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a pre-sorted array, what you need is to find ranges.

Once you have the range, you can then output that set of rows.

Here's an example:

```
echo "<table><tr><td>fruit</td><td>rating</td><td>rank</td></tr>";
$total = count($fruits);
for( $i=0; $i<$total; $i=$range_end+1) {
    $range_start = $i;
    while($i+1 < $total && $fruits[$i]['rating'] == $fruits[$i+1]['rating']) {
        $i++;
    }
    $range_end = $i;

    $range = array_slice($fruits, $range_start, $range_end-$range_start+1);
    foreach($range as $fruit) {
        echo "<tr>"
            ."<td>".$fruit['fruit']."</td>"
            ."<td>".$fruit['rating']."</td>"
            ."<td>";
        if( $range_start == $range_end) {
            echo $fruit['rating'];
        }
        else {
            for($j=$range_start; $j<=$range_end; $j++) {
                echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$fruit['fruit'].'" value="'.$j.'">'.$j;
            }
        }
        echo "</td>"
        ."</tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Note the slightly unconventional `for $i` loop. What's happening here is that we're starting the loop at 0, recording the position we are at in `$range_start`, then advancing until the next fruit's rating is different. At that point we have `$range_end`, which may be the same as `$range_start` if there are no fruits with the same rating. Then we extract the range from the `$fruits` array and output it. Once that is done, the loop continues one place past the end of the range we just did.

Comment: This is almost perfect. All I replaced is `echo $fruit['rating'];` if it's the only one in the range to `echo ($i+1);` so that it won't show the `rating` but the proper `rank`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would suggest:

```
$fruits = array(
  array('fruit' => 'Apple', 'rating' => '2'),
  array('fruit' => 'Pear', 'rating' => '3'),
  array('fruit' => 'Peach', 'rating' => '2'),
  array('fruit' => 'Strawberry', 'rating' => '2')
);

// get unique ratings, in descending order
$ratings = array_unique(array_column($fruits, 'rating'));
sort($ratings);
$ratings = array_fill_keys(array_reverse($ratings), array());

// put fruits in their respective rating buckets:
foreach($fruits as $fruit) {
    $ratings[$fruit['rating']][] = $fruit['fruit'];
}

// Generate the HTML table
$html = "<table border=1><tr><th>fruit</th><th>rating</th><th>rank</th></tr>";
$rank = 1;
foreach($ratings as $rating => $fruits) {
    foreach($fruits as $fruit) {
        if (count($fruits) === 1) {
            $rankHtml = "<b>$rank</b>";
        } else {
            $rankHtml = "";
            for ($i = $rank; $i < $rank + count($fruits); $i++) {
                $rankHtml .= "<input type='radio' name='$fruit' value='$i'>$i";
            }
        }
        $html .= "<tr><td>$fruit</td><td>$rating</td><td>$rankHtml</td></tr>\n";
    }
    $rank += count($fruits);
}
$html .= "</table>";

echo $html;
```

As you can see I like to separate the logic from the output. The only `echo` is at the end.

The main characteristic of this method is the intermediate structure, where the fruit names are grouped into separate arrays depending on their common rating. This, I think, results in nicer code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on usort(). This can re-order your array (or clone it) based on a custom function.

[usort](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.usort.php)

Comment: I need the user to tell the order if the rating is equal. The array is already sorted as I mentioned in my question.